# How to schedule a task with PowerShell to run every hour, Monday to Friday between 8 AM to 6 PM

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks

I need to schedule a task to run:

- Monday to Friday
- Every hour from 8 AM to 6 PM

I can do this from the regular task scheduler GUI but since I'm using a group managed service account to run this task, I need to do this from powershell.

I've tried using the `-RepetitionDuration` and `-RepetitionInterval` parameters in the `New-ScheduledTaskTrigger` cmdlet but in order to use that, I need to have the `-once parameter`?

Please advise!

[image]

Comment: What version of PowerShell? Have you looked into importing a scheduled task .xml file that already has the scheduled determined?

Answer (score 4):

This is the approach documented by Microsoft to address this.

***Note:*** 
You must use the setting options provided in the drop down boxes, even though the GUI appears to be freeform fields, they are not.

See:

[Configuring Advanced Scheduled Task Parameters Using PowerShell](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/platformspfe/2015/10/26/configuring-advanced-scheduled-task-parameters-using-powershell)

***The Missing Parameters***

Great, so now we have a script, a scheduled task that runs the script, and it will run every time the server or workstation is started up. But we have failed to meet one of the requirements; the task must also repeat every 10 minutes for 1 day. If you go back and attempt to add a repetition interval or repetition duration you will notice that neither are an option for the -AtStartup parameter:

Through the GUI the scheduled task parameters are available:

But they are not available via the PowerShell New-ScheduledTaskTrigger cmdlet if you choose the -AtStartup parameter. They are available via the -Once parameter but that would not meet the requirements. ***The solution is to directly modify the task's properties using its XML schema.*** This may sound complicated at first but in reality it is very easy and will allow you to modify practically every parameter of the scheduled task.

Step 1  - Get the scheduled task. The first step is to get the scheduled task that you just created and store it in an object.

```
$Task = Get-ScheduledTask -TaskName "SampleScheduledTask"
```

Step 2 - Update the specific property of the task that you wish to modify. For this example we wish to add a repetition duration and a repetition interval.

```
$Task.Triggers.Repetition.Duration = "P1D"
$Task.Triggers.Repetition.Interval = "PT10M"
```

You are probably wondering how I knew P1D would equal a duration of 1 Day and how I knew PT10M would equal a repetition interval of 10 minutes since neither are the typical date/time or timespan values that you are probably used to working with. To get those values I simply configured the duration and interval that I wanted through the GUI then viewed the result through Powershell  using the following command:

```
$Task.Triggers.Repetition | fl *
```

Step 3 - Save the new configuration to the scheduled task. Remember, you must re-enter the credentials for the task here or the operation will fail.

```
$Task | Set-ScheduledTask -User "NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM"
```

Comment: Regarding the "odd" formatting of the Duration/Interval values, those are ISO 8601 durations. You can read more about them here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations