# How to configure Windows 7 to run on an hourly basis between 9:15 AM and 3:15 PM

Tags: windows-7, cron, scheduled-tasks

I have to configure a task that should run every hour from 9:15 AM until 3:15 PM. Which means it should be started at 9:15 AM, 10:15 AM, 11:15 AM, 12:15 PM, 1:15 PM, 2:15 PM and finally 3:15 PM. This is a total of 7 instances.

Windows 7 does not seem to have any way to configure this in the task schedule.
[This question](https://superuser.com/questions/1373275/how-to-schedule-a-task-with-powershell-to-run-every-hour-monday-to-friday-betwe) is the closest that I have as a solution. However, in this also, it shows that Windows 7 has got an option of running a task every of it for 10 hours and not for 7 hours. In fact, I don't even have the option for 10 hours on my Windows 7 machine.

Is there any other way to check for this? Or is there any other utility that can be used to have a customised schedule, just like we have cron on Unix/Linux

Thank you for any inputs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Task scheduler is not limited to just 1 trigger.

If you setup a daily trigger for 9:15 AM, and another one for 10:15 am and more you can accomplish your task.

Alternatively and probably even better, you can set just 1 trigger at 9:15, make it repeat every hour, and for the duration change it to 12 hours, then edit the 12 and replace it by 7.

Yes, it is just a textfield with some predefined options, but it is text, and Task Scheduler is very smart in understanding it if you change a number.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the text part in task scheduler repeat text box